# RStudio - RMarkdown - Knit to PDF will create a pdf that shows the code used but not the results of code

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I can knit pdf fine but the pdf will show the code I have written but not the results of the code. e.g. PDF will show `nrow(dataset)` but not the answer `31 rows`.

Set up chunk looks like this;

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = TRUE,
    message = TRUE,
    warning = TRUE
)
```

I have checked my RMD settings and they can be seen in the image below: all looks ok.

[image: RMD Settings]

I am hoping if someone might have a resolution for this so the results or answers of my code will be shown in the RMD knitted pdf file?

Comment: What about `eval = TRUE`?